# not good display autoescape in django test project?

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-templates

How to adjust the project to improve the performance result:

in myworld/members/view.py:

```
def testing(request):
template = loader.get_template('template.html')
context = {
    'heading': 'Hello &lt;i&gt;my&lt;/i&gt; World!',
}
print(context)
return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

in myworld/members/templates/template.html :

```
    <html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Learning_21_1_1</title>
</head>
<body>

    {% autoescape off %}
        <h1>{{ heading }}</h1>
    {% endautoescape %}


    <p>Check out views.py to see what the heading variable looks like.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

result :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EqXM.png)

main result :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koMcH.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5rEh.png)

please help me

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## ===== put like this in (views.py) ========

```
context = {'heading': 'Hello <i>my</i> World!'}
```

## ==== Html code ======

```
{% autoescape off %}
  <h1>{{heading}}</h1>
{% endautoescape %}
```

## ==== Html result ======

[image]

## for more information about autoescape

https://www.djangotemplatetagsandfilters.com/tags/autoescape/

Comment: Thak you  very much

Comment: Hello, I now understand the reason for this error, thank you very much for your help